# Would I know if my answer to question why I leave my last company acceptable?

Tags: interviewing, pre-screening

My situation is, when I joined my last company, my title is senior software engineer. When I joined the team for two weeks, I was assigned to a new team. In that moment, there was no source code yet for that team, we needed to build everything from scretch.

Then I took my responsiblity to build everything with other teammates. However, after 4 months, my manager told me: "Hey Jose, you see, this is a completely new team, and we need a tech lead here. Would you take a tech lead role?". Then I had to took this title to work, although he knew I don't have any experience on it.

However, two months later, nearly my probation end, he told me that I am not senior enough to take a tech lead role, but we still need a tech lead. Then had to let me go. Even I requested I can come back to be a SSE.

So now I have to find a new position, but when HR ask me the reason I left, would this answer could be satisfied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. You can tell HR the truth, and the truth will satisfy HR, your manager, and the company.

I don't see how else the answer to HR could be.

Unfortunately, business need shifts or changes the requirements for different roles. You simply tell them that you were affected by this situation.

You should not worry about whether HR or your manager like your truthful answer or not because this is not a negative answer that is intended to hurt anyone.

IMHO, if HR and the manager are being professional, they would really prefer that you tell the truth also.

Answer (score 3):

If you were promoted or your job title was changed you should have taken that in writing.

> So now I have to find a new position, but when HR ask me the reason I left, would this answer could be satisfied?

The truthful reason may work for you or against you. It depends from person to person.

Looking for new opportunities is a good start. If they grill you on this you can tell them the real reason. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

> So now I have to find a new position, but when HR ask me the reason I
> left, would this answer could be satisfied?

You should always tell the truth.

But I think you are asking if the hiring company would like to hear your truthful answer or not. And if that's the case, nobody here can really know.

Comment: well if more than half companies or HR can accept this reason, I consider it is acceptable, not one specific company